# Is there a way to trim/strip whitespace in multiple columns of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with 5 columns and 3 of those columns are string columns. I want to trim all the leading and trailing whitespaces in those 3 columns. Is there a way to achieve this in one go.

```
  ID    col_1  col_2    col_3   col_4
0  1      AA     XX      200     PP
1  2      BB     YY      300     QQ
2  3      CC     ZZ      500     RR
```

I want to trim `'col_1', 'col_2', 'col_4'`

I know `df['col_1'].str.strip()` works on a individual column. But can i do all the columns at one go?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with list of columns:

```
cols = ['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_4']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())
```

Or parse only object columns, it is obviously strings:

```
cols = df.select_dtypes(object).columns
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())
```

Comment: check datatype before using strip. `if df[cols].dtype == 'object':` . Or else it will give you type error.

Answer (score 3):

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
```

Comment: OP wants to strip the columns, not the column names

Comment: This answer was useful to me because I DID want to strip the column names. Thank you very much, Gray!