# Returns an empty dataframe at filtering dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to filter a dataframe that I created by extracting rows from various .csv. When I try to do, for example, `df_data["GPS_COD_SINRUT"]`, it prints:

```
1           T307 E0 00R
2           T307 C0 00I
3           T307 C0 00R
4           T307 C0 00R
               ...     
2069747     T307 E0 00R
2069748     T307 C0 00I
2069749     T307 C0 00I
2069750     T307 C0 00I
2069751     T307 C0 00I
Name: GPS_COD_SINRUT, Length: 2069752, dtype: object
```

But when I try to do: `df_data[df_data["GPS_COD_SINRUT"]=="T307 C0 00R"]`, prints an empty dataframe. I've got another dataframe with the same columns but different values, and it works perfectly. The other columns of df_data are numbers, and it works fine when I try to filter a value. I've tried to put an `str()` before the value that I'm searching, and try to convert the column to string values with `.astype(str)`. I think maybe its the code when I extract the data, but I haven't change anything. The code is:

```
outfile = open('output2.csv', 'w')
outfile.write("Patente; GPS_COD_SINRUT; idx_user; Date; LAT; LON, x_UTM; y_UTM; dist_rute; dist_to_rute; velocity; idx_empresa; idx_expedition")
for filename in glob.glob('*.gps'):
  if filename == 'output2.csv': # Skip the file we're writing.
    continue
  with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
    count = 0 
    lineno = 0 
    for line in infile:
      lineno += 1
      if lineno == 1: # Skip the header line.
        continue
      fields = line.split(';')
      Patente = str(fields[0])
      GPS_COD_SINRUT= str(fields[1])
      idx_user = str(fields[2])
      Date = str(fields[3])
      LAT = float(fields[4])
      LON = float(fields[5])
      x_UTM = float(fields[6])
      y_UTM = float(fields[7])
      dist_rute = float(fields[8])
      dist_to_rute = float(fields[9])
      velocity = float(fields[10])
      idx_empresa = str(fields[11])
      idx_expedition = str(fields[12])
      if "307" in idx_user:
        outfile.write('%s; %s; %s; %s; %f; %f; %f; %f; %f; %f; %f; %s; %s' % (Patente, GPS_COD_SINRUT, idx_user, Date, LAT, LON, x_UTM, y_UTM, dist_rute, dist_to_rute, velocity, idx_empresa, idx_expedition))
        count += 1
    if count == 0: # Handle the case when no lines were found.
      outfile.write('NA ; NA ; NA ; NA ; NA ; NA ; NA ; NA ; NA ; NA ; NA ; NA; NA ; %s\n' % filename)
outfile.close()
```

I found this code as the answer of a question here in SO. I hope you can help me please!

Comment: You might be facing 'whitespace' issues.  Try.`df_data[df_data["GPS_COD_SINRUT"].str.strip()="T307 C0 00R"]`

Comment: Thanks! it works now. Does exist a code or function that solutionates that whitespace issues?I mean to applicate to all the dataframe

Comment: Edit: I found the answer to the comment above :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58287398/is-there-a-way-to-trim-strip-whitespace-in-multiple-columns-of-a-pandas-datafram
Thanks!