# Why I am getting blank DataFrame after the filter?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I wan to filter data which has `"Degree status" == "HS-grad"` & High school graduate.

I tried doing this:

```
HS_grad = census_data2[census_data2["Degree Status"]=="HS-grad"]
print(HS_grad)
```

However when I print it I get empty DataFrame.

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Employment Type, Degree Status, Marriage-Status, Job-Role, Family-Role, Ethnicity, Gender, Country, Earnings]
Index: []
```

This is the dataset which I have renamed the header:

[image: dataset]

Comment: Could you provide us with the head of the DataFrame ? -- example of the data, more info about it?

Comment: seems like you're filtering for `'HS-grad'` instead of `HS-grad`, you used two pairs of quotes there.

Comment: Does the `"Degree Status"` column really contain literal single quotes?

Comment: I have checked with both 'HS-grad' and HS-grad. I am getting blank dataframe for in both cases

Comment: It is not possible to tell what the issue is without being able to recreate your DataFrame, exactly as it appears on your end. The output from `print(census_data2.head(10).to_dict())` (before filtering) would be particularly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything wrong from my perspective,

```
df = DataFrame([{"test name": 1}])
print(df[df["test name"]==1])
```

yields

```
   test name
0          1
```

Is it possible there's whitespace in the entry for "HS-grad"?

Answer (score 0):

[Returns an empty dataframe at filtering dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61807282/returns-an-empty-dataframe-at-filtering-dataframe)
Try this. Works.

```
ind_poor = df_filter[(df_filter["Degree Status"].str.strip() == "HS-grad") & (df_filter["Earnings"].str.strip() == "<=50K")]
```