# sns.barplot() hue corresponding to y value

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

I have some data on countries, and I'm making a bar chart for each region's percentage of GDP based on agriculture. The bars for each region are ordered according to that region's GDP. I've tried adjusting the hue to correspond to each region's average 'Agriculture', but there are mismatches. Hoping someone can help spot my error.

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable

# Assuming `stats` is a DataFrame containing columns 'GDP', 'Region', and 'Agriculture'

# First, sort the DataFrame by GDP
sorted_stats = stats.sort_values('GDP')

# Normalize the 'Agriculture' values
norm = mcolors.Normalize(vmin=sorted_stats['Agriculture'].min(), vmax=sorted_stats['Agriculture'].max())

# Create a colormap
cmap = plt.get_cmap('viridis')

# Generate colors based on normalized 'Agriculture' values
bar_colors = [cmap(norm(value)) for value in sorted_stats['Agriculture']]

# Create a bar plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
sns.barplot(data=sorted_stats, x='Region', y='Agriculture', label="Agriculture (Total Factor Productivity)", ax=ax, palette=bar_colors)

# Set plot title and rotate x-axis labels
plt.title("Regional Average Agriculture (Total Factor Productivity)")
plt.xticks(rotation=90)

# Create a ScalarMappable for the colormap
sm = ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
sm.set_array([])

# Add a colorbar legend
cbar = plt.colorbar(sm)
cbar.set_label('Agriculture (Total Factor Productivity)', rotation=270, labelpad=20)

# Display the plot
plt.show()
```

[image: Output]

[Data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AnZKTw1fITLe6RlVODKhVm6XF3bnPZeQ/view?usp=share_link)

```
Country,Region,Population,Area,Pop. Density,Coastline,Net migration,Infant mortality,GDP,Literacy,Phones,Arable,Crops,Other,Climate,Birthrate,Deathrate,Agriculture,Industry,Service
Afghanistan ,ASIA (EX. NEAR EAST)         ,31056997,647500,48.0,0.0,23.06,163.07,700.0,36.0,3.2,12.13,0.22,87.65,1.0,46.6,20.34,0.38,0.24,0.38
Albania ,EASTERN EUROPE                     ,3581655,28748,124.6,1.26,-4.93,21.52,4500.0,86.5,71.2,21.09,4.42,74.49,3.0,15.11,5.22,0.232,0.188,0.579
Algeria ,NORTHERN AFRICA                    ,32930091,2381740,13.8,0.04,-0.39,31.0,6000.0,70.0,78.1,3.22,0.25,96.53,1.0,17.14,4.61,0.101,0.6,0.298
American Samoa ,OCEANIA                            ,57794,199,290.4,58.29,-20.71,9.27,8000.0,97.0,259.5,10.0,15.0,75.0,2.0,22.46,3.27,,,
Andorra ,WESTERN EUROPE                     ,71201,468,152.1,0.0,6.6,4.05,19000.0,100.0,497.2,2.22,0.0,97.78,3.0,8.71,6.25,,,
Angola ,SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                 ,12127071,1246700,9.7,0.13,0.0,191.19,1900.0,42.0,7.8,2.41,0.24,97.35,,45.11,24.2,0.096,0.658,0.246
Anguilla ,LATIN AMER. & CARIB    ,13477,102,132.1,59.8,10.76,21.03,8600.0,95.0,460.0,0.0,0.0,100.0,2.0,14.17,5.34,0.04,0.18,0.78
Antigua & Barbuda ,LATIN AMER. & CARIB    ,69108,443,156.0,34.54,-6.15,19.46,11000.0,89.0,549.9,18.18,4.55,77.27,2.0,16.93,5.37,0.038,0.22,0.743
Argentina ,LATIN AMER. & CARIB    ,39921833,2766890,14.4,0.18,0.61,15.18,11200.0,97.1,220.4,12.31,0.48,87.21,3.0,16.73,7.55,0.095,0.358,0.547
Armenia ,C.W. OF IND. STATES ,2976372,29800,99.9,0.0,-6.47,23.28,3500.0,98.6,195.7,17.55,2.3,80.15,4.0,12.07,8.23,0.239,0.343,0.418
Aruba ,LATIN AMER. & CARIB    ,71891,193,372.5,35.49,0.0,5.89,28000.0,97.0,516.1,10.53,0.0,89.47,2.0,11.03,6.68,0.004,0.333,0.663
Australia ,OCEANIA                            ,20264082,7686850,2.6,0.34,3.98,4.69,29000.0,100.0,565.5,6.55,0.04,93.41,1.0,12.14,7.51,0.038,0.262,0.7
Austria ,WESTERN EUROPE                     ,8192880,83870,97.7,0.0,2.0,4.66,30000.0,98.0,452.2,16.91,0.86,82.23,3.0,8.74,9.76,0.018,0.304,0.678
Azerbaijan ,C.W. OF IND. STATES ,7961619,86600,91.9,0.0,-4.9,81.74,3400.0,97.0,137.1,19.63,2.71,77.66,1.0,20.74,9.75,0.141,0.457,0.402
Bahamas. The ,LATIN AMER. & CARIB    ,303770,13940,21.8,25.41,-2.2,25.21,16700.0,95.6,460.6,0.8,0.4,98.8,2.0,17.57,9.05,0.03,0.07,0.9
Bahrain ,NEAR EAST                          ,698585,665,1050.5,24.21,1.05,17.27,16900.0,89.1,281.3,2.82,5.63,91.55,1.0,17.8,4.14,0.005,0.387,0.608
Bangladesh ,ASIA (EX. NEAR EAST)         ,147365352,144000,1023.4,0.4,-0.71,62.6,1900.0,43.1,7.3,62.11,3.07,34.82,2.0,29.8,8.27,0.199,0.198,0.603
Barbados ,LATIN AMER. & CARIB    ,279912,431,649.5,22.51,-0.31,12.5,15700.0,97.4,481.9,37.21,2.33,60.46,2.0,12.71,8.67,0.06,0.16,0.78
Belarus ,C.W. OF IND. STATES ,10293011,207600,49.6,0.0,2.54,13.37,6100.0,99.6,319.1,29.55,0.6,69.85,4.0,11.16,14.02,0.093,0.316,0.591
Belgium ,WESTERN EUROPE                     ,10379067,30528,340.0,0.22,1.23,4.68,29100.0,98.0,462.6,23.28,0.4,76.32,3.0,10.38,10.27,0.01,0.24,0.749
Belize ,LATIN AMER. & CARIB    ,287730,22966,12.5,1.68,0.0,25.69,4900.0,94.1,115.7,2.85,1.71,95.44,2.0,28.84,5.72,0.142,0.152,0.612
Benin ,SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                 ,7862944,112620,69.8,0.11,0.0,85.0,1100.0,40.9,9.7,18.08,2.4,79.52,2.0,38.85,12.22,0.316,0.138,0.546
Bermuda ,NORTHERN AMERICA                   ,65773,53,1241.0,194.34,2.49,8.53,36000.0,98.0,851.4,20.0,0.0,80.0,2.0,11.4,7.74,0.01,0.1,0.89
Bhutan ,ASIA (EX. NEAR EAST)         ,2279723,47000,48.5,0.0,0.0,100.44,1300.0,42.2,14.3,3.09,0.43,96.48,2.0,33.65,12.7,0.258,0.379,0.363
Bolivia ,LATIN AMER. & CARIB    ,8989046,1098580,8.2,0.0,-1.32,53.11,2400.0,87.2,71.9,2.67,0.19,97.14,1.5,23.3,7.53,0.128,0.352,0.52
Bosnia & Herzegovina ,EASTERN EUROPE                     ,4498976,51129,88.0,0.04,0.31,21.05,6100.0,,215.4,13.6,2.96,83.44,4.0,8.77,8.27,0.142,0.308,0.55
Botswana ,SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                 ,1639833,600370,2.7,0.0,0.0,54.58,9000.0,79.8,80.5,0.65,0.01,99.34,1.0,23.08,29.5,0.024,0.469,0.507
Brazil ,LATIN AMER. & CARIB    ,188078227,8511965,22.1,0.09,-0.03,29.61,7600.0,86.4,225.3,6.96,0.9,92.15,2.0,16.56,6.17,0.084,0.4,0.516
British Virgin Is. ,LATIN AMER. & CARIB    ,23098,153,151.0,52.29,10.01,18.05,16000.0,97.8,506.5,20.0,6.67,73.33,2.0,14.89,4.42,0.018,0.062,0.92
Brunei ,ASIA (EX. NEAR EAST)         ,379444,5770,65.8,2.79,3.59,12.61,18600.0,93.9,237.2,0.57,0.76,98.67,2.0,18.79,3.45,0.036,0.561,0.403
Bulgaria ,EASTERN EUROPE                     ,7385367,110910,66.6,0.32,-4.58,20.55,7600.0,98.6,336.3,40.02,1.92,58.06,3.0,9.65,14.27,0.093,0.304,0.603
Burkina Faso ,SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                 ,13902972,274200,50.7,0.0,0.0,97.57,1100.0,26.6,7.0,14.43,0.19,85.38,2.0,45.62,15.6,0.322,0.196,0.482
Burma ,ASIA (EX. NEAR EAST)         ,47382633,678500,69.8,0.28,-1.8,67.24,1800.0,85.3,10.1,15.19,0.97,83.84,2.0,17.91,9.83,0.564,0.082,0.353
Burundi ,SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                 ,8090068,27830,290.7,0.0,-0.06,69.29,600.0,51.6,3.4,35.05,14.02,50.93,2.0,42.22,13.46,0.463,0.203,0.334
Cambodia ,ASIA (EX. NEAR EAST)         ,13881427,181040,76.7,0.24,0.0,71.48,1900.0,69.4,2.6,20.96,0.61,78.43,2.0,26.9,9.06,0.35,0.3,0.35
Cameroon ,SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                 ,17340702,475440,36.5,0.08,0.0,68.26,1800.0,79.0,5.7,12.81,2.58,84.61,1.5,33.89,13.47,0.448,0.17,0.382
Canada ,NORTHERN AMERICA                   ,33098932,9984670,3.3,2.02,5.96,4.75,29800.0,97.0,552.2,4.96,0.02,95.02,,10.78,7.8,0.022,0.294,0.684
Cape Verde ,SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                 ,420979,4033,104.4,23.93,-12.07,47.77,1400.0,76.6,169.6,9.68,0.5,89.82,3.0,24.87,6.55,0.121,0.219,0.66
Cayman Islands ,LATIN AMER. & CARIB    ,45436,262,173.4,61.07,18.75,8.19,35000.0,98.0,836.3,3.85,0.0,96.15,2.0,12.74,4.89,0.014,0.032,0.954
Central African Rep. ,SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                 ,4303356,622984,6.9,0.0,0.0,91.0,1100.0,51.0,2.3,3.1,0.14,96.76,2.0,33.91,18.65,0.55,0.2,0.25
Chad ,SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                 ,9944201,1284000,7.7,0.0,-0.11,93.82,1200.0,47.5,1.3,2.86,0.02,97.12,2.0,45.73,16.38,0.335,0.259,0.406
Chile ,LATIN AMER. & CARIB    ,16134219,756950,21.3,0.85,0.0,8.8,9900.0,96.2,213.0,2.65,0.42,96.93,3.0,15.23,5.81,0.06,0.493,0.447
China ,ASIA (EX. NEAR EAST)         ,1313973713,9596960,136.9,0.15,-0.4,24.18,5000.0,90.9,266.7,15.4,1.25,83.35,1.5,13.25,6.97,0.125,0.473,0.403
Colombia ,LATIN AMER. & CARIB    ,43593035,1138910,38.3,0.28,-0.31,20.97,6300.0,92.5,176.2,2.42,1.67,95.91,2.0,20.48,5.58,0.125,0.342,0.533
Comoros ,SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                 ,690948,2170,318.4,15.67,0.0,74.93,700.0,56.5,24.5,35.87,23.32,40.81,2.0,36.93,8.2,0.4,0.04,0.56
Congo. Dem. Rep. ,SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                 ,62660551,2345410,26.7,0.0,0.0,94.69,700.0,65.5,0.2,2.96,0.52,96.52,2.0,43.69,13.27,0.55,0.11,0.34
Congo. Repub. of the ,SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                 ,3702314,342000,10.8,0.05,-0.17,93.86,700.0,83.8,3.7,0.51,0.13,99.36,2.0,42.57,12.93,0.062,0.57,0.369
Cook Islands ,OCEANIA                            ,21388,240,89.1,50.0,,,5000.0,95.0,289.9,17.39,13.04,69.57,2.0,21.0,,0.151,0.096,0.753
Costa Rica ,LATIN AMER. & CARIB    ,4075261,51100,79.8,2.52,0.51,9.95,9100.0,96.0,340.7,4.41,5.88,89.71,2.0,18.32,4.36,0.088,0.299,0.614
Cote d'Ivoire ,SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                 ,17654843,322460,54.8,0.16,-0.07,90.83,1400.0,50.9,14.6,9.75,13.84,76.41,2.0,35.11,14.84,0.279,0.171,0.55
Croatia ,EASTERN EUROPE                     ,4494749,56542,79.5,10.32,1.58,6.84,10600.0,98.5,420.4,26.09,2.27,71.65,,9.61,11.48,0.07,0.308,0.622
Cuba ,LATIN AMER. & CARIB    ,11382820,110860,102.7,3.37,-1.58,6.33,2900.0,97.0,74.7,33.05,7.6,59.35,2.0,11.89,7.22,0.055,0.261,0.684
Cyprus ,NEAR EAST                          ,784301,9250,84.8,7.01,0.43,7.18,19200.0,97.6,,7.79,4.44,87.77,3.0,12.56,7.68,0.037,0.198,0.765
Czech Republic ,EASTERN EUROPE                     ,10235455,78866,129.8,0.0,0.97,3.93,15700.0,99.9,314.3,39.8,3.05,57.15,3.0,9.02,10.59,0.034,0.393,0.573
Denmark ,WESTERN EUROPE                     ,5450661,43094,126.5,16.97,2.48,4.56,31100.0,100.0,614.6,54.02,0.19,45.79,3.0,11.13,10.36,0.018,0.246,0.735
Djibouti ,SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                 ,486530,23000,21.2,1.37,0.0,104.13,1300.0,67.9,22.8,0.04,0.0,99.96,1.0,39.53,19.31,0.179,0.225,0.596
Dominica ,LATIN AMER. & CARIB    ,68910,754,91.4,19.63,-13.87,14.15,5400.0,94.0,304.8,6.67,20.0,73.33,2.0,15.27,6.73,0.177,0.328,0.495
Dominican Republic ,LATIN AMER. & CARIB    ,9183984,48730,188.5,2.64,-3.22,32.38,6000.0,84.7,97.4,22.65,10.33,67.02,2.0,23.22,5.73,0.112,0.306,0.582
East Timor ,ASIA (EX. NEAR EAST)         ,1062777,15007,70.8,4.7,0.0,47.41,500.0,58.6,,4.71,0.67,94.62,2.0,26.99,6.24,0.085,0.231,0.684
Ecuador ,LATIN AMER. & CARIB    ,13547510,283560,47.8,0.79,-8.58,23.66,3300.0,92.5,125.6,5.85,4.93,89.22,2.0,22.29,4.23,0.07,0.312,0.618
Egypt ,NORTHERN AFRICA                    ,78887007,1001450,78.8,0.24,-0.22,32.59,4000.0,57.7,131.8,2.87,0.48,96.65,1.0,22.94,5.23,0.149,0.357,0.493
El Salvador ,LATIN AMER. & CARIB    ,6822378,21040,324.3,1.46,-3.74,25.1,4800.0,80.2,142.4,31.85,12.07,56.08,2.0,26.61,5.78,0.099,0.302,0.599
Equatorial Guinea ,SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                 ,540109,28051,19.3,1.06,0.0,85.13,2700.0,85.7,18.5,4.63,3.57,91.8,2.0,35.59,15.06,0.03,0.906,0.062
Eritrea ,SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                 ,4786994,121320,39.5,1.84,0.0,74.87,700.0,58.6,7.9,4.95,0.03,95.02,1.5,34.33,9.6,0.102,0.254,0.643
Estonia ,BALTICS                            ,1324333,45226,29.3,8.39,-3.16,7.87,12300.0,99.8,333.8,16.04,0.45,83.51,3.0,10.04,13.25,0.04,0.294,0.666
Ethiopia ,SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                 ,74777981,1127127,66.3,0.0,0.0,95.32,700.0,42.7,8.2,10.71,0.75,88.54,2.0,37.98,14.86,0.475,0.099,0.426
Faroe Islands ,WESTERN EUROPE                     ,47246,1399,33.8,79.84,1.41,6.24,22000.0,,503.8,2.14,0.0,97.86,,14.05,8.7,0.27,0.11,0.62
Fiji ,OCEANIA                            ,905949,18270,49.6,6.18,-3.14,12.62,5800.0,93.7,112.6,10.95,4.65,84.4,2.0,22.55,5.65,0.089,0.135,0.776
Finland ,WESTERN EUROPE                     ,5231372,338145,15.5,0.37,0.95,3.57,27400.0,100.0,405.3,7.19,0.03,92.78,3.0,10.45,9.86,0.028,0.295,0.676
France ,WESTERN EUROPE                     ,60876136,547030,111.3,0.63,0.66,4.26,27600.0,99.0,586.4,33.53,2.07,64.4,4.0,11.99,9.14,0.022,0.214,0.764
French Guiana ,LATIN AMER. & CARIB    ,199509,91000,2.2,0.42,6.27,12.07,8300.0,83.0,255.6,0.14,0.05,99.81,2.0,20.46,4.88,0.066,0.156,0.778
French Polynesia ,OCEANIA                            ,274578,4167,65.9,60.6,2.94,8.44,17500.0,98.0,194.5,0.82,5.46,93.72,2.0,16.68,4.69,0.031,0.19,0.769
Gabon ,SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                 ,1424906,267667,5.3,0.33,0.0,53.64,5500.0,63.2,27.4,1.26,0.66,98.08,2.0,36.16,12.25,0.061,0.592,0.348
Gambia. The ,SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                 ,1641564,11300,145.3,0.71,1.57,72.02,1700.0,40.1,26.8,25.0,0.5,74.5,2.0,39.37,12.25,0.308,0.142,0.549
Gaza Strip ,NEAR EAST                          ,1428757,360,3968.8,11.11,1.6,22.93,600.0,,244.3,28.95,21.05,50.0,3.0,39.45,3.8,0.03,0.283,0.687
Georgia ,C.W. OF IND. STATES ,4661473,69700,66.9,0.44,-4.7,18.59,2500.0,99.0,146.6,11.44,3.86,84.7,3.0,10.41,9.23,0.172,0.275,0.553
Germany ,WESTERN EUROPE                     ,82422299,357021,230.9,0.67,2.18,4.16,27600.0,99.0,667.9,33.85,0.59,65.56,3.0,8.25,10.62,0.009,0.296,0.695
Ghana ,SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                 ,22409572,239460,93.6,0.23,-0.64,51.43,2200.0,74.8,14.4,16.26,9.67,74.07,2.0,30.52,9.72,0.366,0.246,0.387
Gibraltar ,WESTERN EUROPE                     ,27928,7,3989.7,171.43,0.0,5.13,17500.0,,877.7,0.0,0.0,100.0,,10.74,9.31,,,
Greece ,WESTERN EUROPE                     ,10688058,131940,81.0,10.37,2.35,5.53,20000.0,97.5,589.7,21.1,8.78,70.12,3.0,9.68,10.24,0.054,0.213,0.733
Greenland ,NORTHERN AMERICA                   ,56361,2166086,0.0,2.04,-8.37,15.82,20000.0,,448.9,0.0,0.0,100.0,1.0,15.93,7.84,,,
Grenada ,LATIN AMER. & CARIB    ,89703,344,260.8,35.17,-13.92,14.62,5000.0,98.0,364.5,5.88,29.41,64.71,2.0,22.08,6.88,0.054,0.18,0.766
Guadeloupe ,LATIN AMER. & CARIB    ,452776,1780,254.4,17.19,-0.15,8.6,8000.0,90.0,463.8,11.24,3.55,85.21,2.0,15.05,6.09,0.15,0.17,0.68
Guam ,OCEANIA                            ,171019,541,316.1,23.2,0.0,6.94,21000.0,99.0,492.0,9.09,16.36,74.55,2.0,18.79,4.48,,,
Guatemala ,LATIN AMER. & CARIB    ,12293545,108890,112.9,0.37,-1.67,35.93,4100.0,70.6,92.1,12.54,5.03,82.43,2.0,29.88,5.2,0.227,0.188,0.585
Guernsey ,WESTERN EUROPE                     ,65409,78,838.6,64.1,3.84,4.71,20000.0,,842.4,,,,3.0,8.81,10.01,0.03,0.1,0.87
Guinea ,SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                 ,9690222,245857,39.4,0.13,-3.06,90.37,2100.0,35.9,2.7,3.63,2.58,93.79,2.0,41.76,15.48,0.237,0.362,0.401
Guinea-Bissau ,SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                 ,1442029,36120,39.9,0.97,-1.57,107.17,800.0,42.4,7.4,10.67,8.82,80.51,2.0,37.22,16.53,0.62,0.12,0.26
Guyana ,LATIN AMER. & CARIB    ,767245,214970,3.6,0.21,-2.07,33.26,4000.0,98.8,143.5,2.44,0.15,97.41,2.0,18.28,8.28,0.37,0.203,0.427
Haiti ,LATIN AMER. & CARIB    ,8308504,27750,299.4,6.38,-3.4,73.45,1600.0,52.9,16.9,28.3,11.61,60.09,2.0,36.44,12.17,0.28,0.2,0.52
Honduras ,LATIN AMER. & CARIB    ,7326496,112090,65.4,0.73,-1.99,29.32,2600.0,76.2,67.5,9.55,3.22,87.23,2.0,28.24,5.28,0.139,0.312,0.549
Hong Kong ,ASIA (EX. NEAR EAST)         ,6940432,1092,6355.7,67.12,5.24,2.97,28800.0,93.5,546.7,5.05,1.01,93.94,2.0,7.29,6.29,0.001,0.092,0.906
Hungary ,EASTERN EUROPE                     ,9981334,93030,107.3,0.0,0.86,8.57,13900.0,99.4,336.2,50.09,2.06,47.85,3.0,9.72,13.11,0.037,0.312,0.651
Iceland ,WESTERN EUROPE                     ,299388,103000,2.9,4.83,2.38,3.31,30900.0,99.9,647.7,0.07,0.0,99.93,3.0,13.64,6.72,0.086,0.15,0.765
India ,ASIA (EX. NEAR EAST)         ,1095351995,3287590,333.2,0.21,-0.07,56.29,2900.0,59.5,45.4,54.4,2.74,42.86,2.5,22.01,8.18,0.186,0.276,0.538
Indonesia ,ASIA (EX. NEAR EAST)         ,245452739,1919440,127.9,2.85,0.0,35.6,3200.0,87.9,52.0,11.32,7.23,81.45,2.0,20.34,6.25,0.134,0.458,0.408
Iran ,ASIA (EX. NEAR EAST)         ,68688433,1648000,41.7,0.15,-0.84,41.58,7000.0,79.4,276.4,8.72,1.39,89.89,1.0,17.0,5.55,0.116,0.424,0.46
Iraq ,NEAR EAST                          ,26783383,437072,61.3,0.01,0.0,50.25,1500.0,40.4,38.6,13.15,0.78,86.07,1.0,31.98,5.37,0.073,0.666,0.261
Ireland ,WESTERN EUROPE                     ,4062235,70280,57.8,2.06,4.99,5.39,29600.0,98.0,500.5,15.2,0.03,84.77,3.0,14.45,7.82,0.05,0.46,0.49
Isle of Man ,WESTERN EUROPE                     ,75441,572,131.9,27.97,5.36,5.93,21000.0,,676.0,9.0,0.0,91.0,3.0,11.05,11.19,0.01,0.13,0.86
Israel ,NEAR EAST                          ,6352117,20770,305.8,1.31,0.68,7.03,19800.0,95.4,462.3,16.39,4.17,79.44,3.0,17.97,6.18,0.026,0.317,0.657
Italy ,WESTERN EUROPE                     ,58133509,301230,193.0,2.52,2.07,5.94,26700.0,98.6,430.9,27.79,9.53,62.68,,8.72,10.4,0.021,0.291,0.688
Jamaica ,LATIN AMER. & CARIB    ,2758124,10991,250.9,9.3,-4.92,12.36,3900.0,87.9,124.0,16.07,10.16,73.77,2.0,20.82,6.52,0.049,0.337,0.615
Japan ,ASIA (EX. NEAR EAST)         ,127463611,377835,337.4,7.87,0.0,3.26,28200.0,99.0,461.2,12.19,0.96,86.85,3.0,9.37,9.16,0.017,0.258,0.725
Jersey ,WESTERN EUROPE                     ,91084,116,785.2,60.34,2.76,5.24,24800.0,,811.3,0.0,0.0,100.0,3.0,9.3,9.28,0.05,0.02,0.93
Jordan ,NEAR EAST                          ,5906760,92300,64.0,0.03,6.59,17.35,4300.0,91.3,104.5,2.67,1.83,95.5,1.0,21.25,2.65,0.033,0.287,0.68
Kazakhstan ,C.W. OF IND. STATES ,15233244,2717300,5.6,0.0,-3.35,29.21,6300.0,98.4,164.1,7.98,0.05,91.97,4.0,16.0,9.42,0.067,0.386,0.547
Kenya ,SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                 ,34707817,582650,59.6,0.09,-0.1,61.47,1000.0,85.1,8.1,8.08,0.98,90.94,1.5,39.72,14.02,0.163,0.188,0.651
Kiribati ,OCEANIA                            ,105432,811,130.0,140.94,0.0,48.52,800.0,,42.7,2.74,50.68,46.58,2.0,30.65,8.26,0.089,0.242,0.668
Korea. North ,ASIA (EX. NEAR EAST)         ,23113019,120540,191.8,2.07,0.0,24.04,1300.0,99.0,42.4,20.76,2.49,76.75,3.0,15.54,7.13,0.3,0.34,0.36
Korea. South ,ASIA (EX. NEAR EAST)         ,48846823,98480,496.0,2.45,0.0,7.05,17800.0,97.9,486.1,17.18,1.95,80.87,3.0,10.0,5.85,0.033,0.403,0.563
Kuwait ,NEAR EAST                          ,2418393,17820,135.7,2.8,14.18,9.95,19000.0,83.5,211.0,0.73,0.11,99.16,1.0,21.94,2.41,0.004,0.479,0.516
Kyrgyzstan ,C.W. OF IND. STATES ,5213898,198500,26.3,0.0,-2.45,35.64,1600.0,97.0,84.0,7.3,0.35,92.35,2.5,22.8,7.08,0.353,0.208,0.439
Laos ,ASIA (EX. NEAR EAST)         ,6368481,236800,26.9,0.0,0.0,85.22,1700.0,66.4,14.1,3.8,0.35,95.85,2.0,35.49,11.55,0.455,0.287,0.258
Latvia ,BALTICS                            ,2274735,64589,35.2,0.82,-2.23,9.55,10200.0,99.8,321.4,29.67,0.47,69.86,3.0,9.24,13.66,0.04,0.261,0.699
Lebanon ,NEAR EAST                          ,3874050,10400,372.5,2.16,0.0,24.52,4800.0,87.4,255.6,16.62,13.98,69.4,,18.52,6.21,0.12,0.21,0.67
Lesotho ,SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                 ,2022331,30355,66.6,0.0,-0.74,84.23,3000.0,84.8,23.7,10.87,0.13,89.0,3.0,24.75,28.71,0.163,0.443,0.394
Liberia ,SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                 ,3042004,111370,27.3,0.52,0.0,128.87,1000.0,57.5,2.3,3.95,2.28,93.77,2.0,44.77,23.1,0.769,0.054,0.177
Libya ,NORTHERN AFRICA                    ,5900754,1759540,3.4,0.1,0.0,24.6,6400.0,82.6,127.1,1.03,0.19,98.78,,26.49,3.48,0.076,0.499,0.425
Liechtenstein ,WESTERN EUROPE                     ,33987,160,212.4,0.0,4.85,4.7,25000.0,100.0,585.5,25.0,0.0,75.0,4.0,10.21,7.18,0.06,0.39,0.55
Lithuania ,BALTICS                            ,3585906,65200,55.0,0.14,-0.71,6.89,11400.0,99.6,223.4,45.22,0.91,53.87,,8.75,10.98,0.055,0.325,0.62
Luxembourg ,WESTERN EUROPE                     ,474413,2586,183.5,0.0,8.97,4.81,55100.0,100.0,515.4,23.28,0.4,76.32,,11.94,8.41,0.01,0.13,0.86
Macau ,ASIA (EX. NEAR EAST)         ,453125,28,16183.0,146.43,4.86,4.39,19400.0,94.5,384.9,0.0,0.0,100.0,2.0,8.48,4.47,0.001,0.072,0.927
Macedonia ,EASTERN EUROPE                     ,2050554,25333,80.9,0.0,-1.45,10.09,6700.0,,260.0,22.26,1.81,75.93,3.0,12.02,8.77,0.118,0.319,0.563
Madagascar ,SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                 ,18595469,587040,31.7,0.82,0.0,76.83,800.0,68.9,3.6,5.07,1.03,93.91,2.0,41.41,11.11,0.276,0.165,0.559
Malawi ,SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                 ,13013926,118480,109.8,0.0,0.0,103.32,600.0,62.7,7.9,23.38,1.49,75.13,2.0,43.13,19.33,0.342,0.158,0.499
Malaysia ,ASIA (EX. NEAR EAST)         ,24385858,329750,74.0,1.42,0.0,17.7,9000.0,88.7,179.0,5.48,17.61,76.91,2.0,22.86,5.05,0.084,0.48,0.436
Maldives ,ASIA (EX. NEAR EAST)         ,359008,300,1196.7,214.67,0.0,56.52,3900.0,97.2,90.0,13.33,16.67,70.0,2.0,34.81,7.06,0.2,0.18,0.62
Mali ,SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                 ,11716829,1240000,9.5,0.0,-0.33,116.79,900.0,46.4,6.4,3.82,0.03,96.15,2.0,49.82,16.89,0.45,0.17,0.38
Malta ,WESTERN EUROPE                     ,400214,316,1266.5,62.28,2.07,3.89,17700.0,92.8,505.0,28.13,3.13,68.74,,10.22,8.1,0.03,0.23,0.74
Marshall Islands ,OCEANIA                            ,60422,11854,5.1,3.12,-6.04,29.45,1600.0,93.7,91.2,16.67,38.89,44.44,2.0,33.05,4.78,0.317,0.149,0.534
Martinique ,LATIN AMER. & CARIB    ,436131,1100,396.5,31.82,-0.05,7.09,14400.0,97.7,394.4,10.38,9.43,80.19,2.0,13.74,6.48,0.06,0.11,0.83
Mauritania ,SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                 ,3177388,1030700,3.1,0.07,0.0,70.89,1800.0,41.7,12.9,0.48,0.01,99.51,1.0,40.99,12.16,0.25,0.29,0.46
Mauritius ,SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                 ,1240827,2040,608.3,8.68,-0.9,15.03,11400.0,85.6,289.3,49.26,2.96,47.78,2.0,15.43,6.86,0.059,0.298,0.643
Mayotte ,SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                 ,201234,374,538.1,49.52,6.78,62.4,2600.0,,49.7,,,,2.0,40.95,7.7,,,
Mexico ,LATIN AMER. & CARIB    ,107449525,1972550,54.5,0.47,-4.87,20.91,9000.0,92.2,181.6,12.99,1.31,85.7,1.5,20.69,4.74,0.038,0.259,0.702
Micronesia. Fed. St. ,OCEANIA                            ,108004,702,153.9,870.66,-20.99,30.21,2000.0,89.0,114.8,5.71,45.71,48.58,2.0,24.68,4.75,0.289,0.152,0.559
Moldova ,C.W. OF IND. STATES ,4466706,33843,132.0,0.0,-0.26,40.42,1800.0,99.1,208.1,55.3,10.79,33.91,,15.7,12.64,0.213,0.233,0.555
Monaco ,WESTERN EUROPE                     ,32543,2,16271.5,205.0,7.75,5.43,27000.0,99.0,1035.6,0.0,0.0,100.0,,9.19,12.91,0.17,,
Mongolia ,ASIA (EX. NEAR EAST)         ,2832224,1564116,1.8,0.0,0.0,53.79,1800.0,97.8,55.1,0.77,0.0,99.23,1.0,21.59,6.95,0.206,0.214,0.58
Montserrat ,LATIN AMER. & CARIB    ,9439,102,92.5,39.22,0.0,7.35,3400.0,97.0,,20.0,0.0,80.0,2.0,17.59,7.1,,,
Morocco ,NORTHERN AFRICA                    ,33241259,446550,74.4,0.41,-0.98,41.62,4000.0,51.7,40.4,19.61,2.17,78.22,,21.98,5.58,0.217,0.357,0.426
Mozambique ,SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                 ,19686505,801590,24.6,0.31,0.0,130.79,1200.0,47.8,3.5,5.1,0.3,94.6,2.0,35.18,21.35,0.262,0.348,0.39
Namibia ,SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                 ,2044147,825418,2.5,0.19,0.0,48.98,7200.0,84.0,62.6,0.99,0.0,99.01,1.0,24.32,18.86,0.097,0.315,0.588
Nauru ,OCEANIA                            ,13287,21,632.7,142.86,0.0,9.95,5000.0,,143.0,0.0,0.0,100.0,2.0,24.76,6.7,,,
Nepal ,ASIA (EX. NEAR EAST)         ,28287147,147181,192.2,0.0,0.0,66.98,1400.0,45.2,15.9,21.68,0.64,77.68,,30.98,9.31,0.38,0.21,0.41
Netherlands ,WESTERN EUROPE                     ,16491461,41526,397.1,1.09,2.91,5.04,28600.0,99.0,460.8,26.71,0.97,72.32,3.0,10.9,8.68,0.021,0.244,0.736
Netherlands Antilles ,LATIN AMER. & CARIB    ,221736,960,231.0,37.92,-0.41,10.03,11400.0,96.7,365.3,10.0,0.0,90.0,2.0,14.78,6.45,0.01,0.15,0.84
New Caledonia ,OCEANIA                            ,219246,19060,11.5,11.83,0.0,7.72,15000.0,91.0,252.2,0.38,0.33,99.29,2.0,18.11,5.69,0.15,0.088,0.762
New Zealand ,OCEANIA                            ,4076140,268680,15.2,5.63,4.05,5.85,21600.0,99.0,441.7,5.6,6.99,87.41,3.0,13.76,7.53,0.043,0.273,0.684
Nicaragua ,LATIN AMER. & CARIB    ,5570129,129494,43.0,0.7,-1.22,29.11,2300.0,67.5,39.7,15.94,1.94,82.12,2.0,24.51,4.45,0.165,0.275,0.56
Niger ,SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                 ,12525094,1267000,9.9,0.0,-0.67,121.69,800.0,17.6,1.9,3.54,0.01,96.45,1.0,50.73,20.91,0.39,0.17,0.44
Nigeria ,SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                 ,131859731,923768,142.7,0.09,0.26,98.8,900.0,68.0,9.3,31.29,2.96,65.75,1.5,40.43,16.94,0.269,0.487,0.244
N. Mariana Islands ,OCEANIA                            ,82459,477,172.9,310.69,9.61,7.11,12500.0,97.0,254.7,13.04,4.35,82.61,2.0,19.43,2.29,,,
Norway ,WESTERN EUROPE                     ,4610820,323802,14.2,7.77,1.74,3.7,37800.0,100.0,461.7,2.87,0.0,97.13,3.0,11.46,9.4,0.021,0.415,0.564
Oman ,NEAR EAST                          ,3102229,212460,14.6,0.98,0.28,19.51,13100.0,75.8,85.5,0.0,0.14,99.74,1.0,36.24,3.81,0.027,0.39,0.583
Pakistan ,ASIA (EX. NEAR EAST)         ,165803560,803940,206.2,0.13,-2.77,72.44,2100.0,45.7,31.8,27.87,0.87,71.26,1.0,29.74,8.23,0.216,0.251,0.533
Palau ,OCEANIA                            ,20579,458,44.9,331.66,2.85,14.84,9000.0,92.0,325.6,8.7,4.35,86.95,2.0,18.03,6.8,0.062,0.12,0.818
Panama ,LATIN AMER. & CARIB    ,3191319,78200,40.8,3.18,-0.91,20.47,6300.0,92.6,137.9,7.36,1.98,90.66,2.0,21.74,5.36,0.068,0.156,0.776
Papua New Guinea ,OCEANIA                            ,5670544,462840,12.3,1.11,0.0,51.45,2200.0,64.6,10.9,0.46,1.44,98.1,2.0,29.36,7.25,0.353,0.381,0.266
Paraguay ,LATIN AMER. & CARIB    ,6506464,406750,16.0,0.0,-0.08,25.63,4700.0,94.0,49.2,7.6,0.23,92.17,2.0,29.1,4.49,0.224,0.207,0.569
Peru ,LATIN AMER. & CARIB    ,28302603,1285220,22.0,0.19,-1.05,31.94,5100.0,90.9,79.5,2.89,0.4,96.71,1.5,20.48,6.23,0.08,0.27,0.65
Philippines ,ASIA (EX. NEAR EAST)         ,89468677,300000,298.2,12.1,-1.5,23.51,4600.0,92.6,38.4,18.95,16.77,64.28,2.0,24.89,5.41,0.144,0.326,0.53
Poland ,EASTERN EUROPE                     ,38536869,312685,123.3,0.16,-0.49,8.51,11100.0,99.8,306.3,45.91,1.12,52.97,3.0,9.85,9.89,0.05,0.311,0.64
Portugal ,WESTERN EUROPE                     ,10605870,92391,114.8,1.94,3.57,5.05,18000.0,93.3,399.2,21.75,7.81,70.44,3.0,10.72,10.5,0.053,0.274,0.673
Puerto Rico ,LATIN AMER. & CARIB    ,3927188,13790,284.8,3.63,-1.46,8.24,16800.0,94.1,283.1,3.95,5.52,90.53,2.0,12.77,7.65,0.01,0.45,0.54
Qatar ,NEAR EAST                          ,885359,11437,77.4,4.92,16.29,18.61,21500.0,82.5,232.0,1.64,0.27,98.09,1.0,15.56,4.72,0.002,0.801,0.197
Reunion ,SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                 ,787584,2517,312.9,8.22,0.0,7.78,5800.0,88.9,380.9,13.6,1.2,85.2,2.0,18.9,5.49,0.08,0.19,0.73
Romania ,EASTERN EUROPE                     ,22303552,237500,93.9,0.09,-0.13,26.43,7000.0,98.4,196.9,40.82,2.25,56.93,3.0,10.7,11.77,0.101,0.35,0.549
Russia ,C.W. OF IND. STATES ,142893540,17075200,8.4,0.22,1.02,15.39,8900.0,99.6,280.6,7.33,0.11,92.56,,9.95,14.65,0.054,0.371,0.575
Rwanda ,SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                 ,8648248,26338,328.4,0.0,0.0,91.23,1300.0,70.4,2.7,40.54,12.16,47.3,3.0,40.37,16.09,0.401,0.229,0.37
Saint Helena ,SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                 ,7502,413,18.2,14.53,0.0,19.0,2500.0,97.0,293.3,12.9,0.0,87.1,,12.13,6.53,,,
Saint Kitts & Nevis ,LATIN AMER. & CARIB    ,39129,261,149.9,51.72,-7.11,14.49,8800.0,97.0,638.9,19.44,2.78,77.78,2.0,18.02,8.33,0.035,0.258,0.707
Saint Lucia ,LATIN AMER. & CARIB    ,168458,616,273.5,25.65,-2.67,13.53,5400.0,67.0,303.3,6.56,22.95,70.49,2.0,19.68,5.08,0.07,0.2,0.73
St Pierre & Miquelon ,NORTHERN AMERICA                   ,7026,242,29.0,49.59,-4.86,7.54,6900.0,99.0,683.2,13.04,0.0,86.96,,13.52,6.83,,,
Saint Vincent and the Grenadines ,LATIN AMER. & CARIB    ,117848,389,303.0,21.59,-7.64,14.78,2900.0,96.0,190.9,17.95,17.95,64.1,2.0,16.18,5.98,0.1,0.26,0.64
Samoa ,OCEANIA                            ,176908,2944,60.1,13.69,-11.7,27.71,5600.0,99.7,75.2,21.2,24.38,54.42,2.0,16.43,6.62,0.114,0.584,0.302
San Marino ,WESTERN EUROPE                     ,29251,61,479.5,0.0,10.98,5.73,34600.0,96.0,704.3,16.67,0.0,83.33,,10.02,8.17,,,
Sao Tome & Principe ,SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                 ,193413,1001,193.2,20.88,-2.72,43.11,1200.0,79.3,36.2,6.25,48.96,44.79,2.0,40.25,6.47,0.167,0.148,0.684
Saudi Arabia ,NEAR EAST                          ,27019731,1960582,13.8,0.13,-2.71,13.24,11800.0,78.8,140.6,1.67,0.09,98.24,1.0,29.34,2.58,0.033,0.613,0.354
Senegal ,SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                 ,11987121,196190,61.1,0.27,0.2,55.51,1600.0,40.2,22.2,12.78,0.21,87.01,2.0,32.78,9.42,0.172,0.209,0.619
Serbia ,EASTERN EUROPE                     ,9396411,88361,106.3,0.0,-1.33,12.89,2200.0,93.0,285.8,33.35,3.2,63.45,,,,0.166,0.255,0.579
Seychelles ,SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                 ,81541,455,179.2,107.91,-5.69,15.53,7800.0,58.0,262.4,2.22,13.33,84.45,2.0,16.03,6.29,0.032,0.304,0.665
Sierra Leone ,SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                 ,6005250,71740,83.7,0.56,0.0,143.64,500.0,31.4,4.0,6.98,0.89,92.13,2.0,45.76,23.03,0.49,0.31,0.21
Singapore ,ASIA (EX. NEAR EAST)         ,4492150,693,6482.2,27.85,11.53,2.29,23700.0,92.5,411.4,1.64,0.0,98.36,2.0,9.34,4.28,0.0,0.339,0.661
Slovakia ,EASTERN EUROPE                     ,5439448,48845,111.4,0.0,0.3,7.41,13300.0,,220.1,30.16,2.62,67.22,3.0,10.65,9.45,0.035,0.294,0.672
Slovenia ,EASTERN EUROPE                     ,2010347,20273,99.2,0.23,1.12,4.45,19000.0,99.7,406.1,8.6,1.49,89.91,,8.98,10.31,0.028,0.369,0.603
Solomon Islands ,OCEANIA                            ,552438,28450,19.4,18.67,0.0,21.29,1700.0,,13.4,0.64,2.0,97.36,2.0,30.01,3.92,0.42,0.11,0.47
Somalia ,SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                 ,8863338,637657,13.9,0.47,5.37,116.7,500.0,37.8,11.3,1.67,0.04,98.29,1.0,45.13,16.63,0.65,0.1,0.25
South Africa ,SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                 ,44187637,1219912,36.2,0.23,-0.29,61.81,10700.0,86.4,107.0,12.08,0.79,87.13,1.0,18.2,22.0,0.025,0.303,0.671
Spain ,WESTERN EUROPE                     ,40397842,504782,80.0,0.98,0.99,4.42,22000.0,97.9,453.5,26.07,9.87,64.06,3.0,10.06,9.72,0.04,0.295,0.665
Sri Lanka ,ASIA (EX. NEAR EAST)         ,20222240,65610,308.2,2.04,-1.31,14.35,3700.0,92.3,61.5,13.86,15.7,70.44,2.0,15.51,6.52,0.178,0.276,0.545
Sudan ,SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                 ,41236378,2505810,16.5,0.03,-0.02,62.5,1900.0,61.1,16.3,6.83,0.18,92.99,2.0,34.53,8.97,0.387,0.203,0.41
Suriname ,LATIN AMER. & CARIB    ,439117,163270,2.7,0.24,-8.81,23.57,4000.0,93.0,184.7,0.37,0.06,99.57,2.0,18.02,7.27,0.13,0.22,0.65
Swaziland ,SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                 ,1136334,17363,65.5,0.0,0.0,69.27,4900.0,81.6,30.8,10.35,0.7,88.95,2.5,27.41,29.74,0.119,0.515,0.366
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but the country and region columns need to be cleaned of whitespace at the ends of the strings. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58287410/7758804)